# In Yosemite, suddenly the application Photos is not open anymore

Tags: photos

Photo.app does not open when clicked on in the dock or in the list of apps.
Message comes up "The application "Photos.app" is not open anymore". How can I re-open it?

Comment: Link to http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/264218/photos-app-not-responding/264272#264272

Answer (score 1):

I'd try clearing the saved state files.

From Finder:

- <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>N</kbd>
- <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>     <kbd>G</kbd>
- Copy/paste `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Photos/Data/Library/Saved Application State`

Find the folder com.apple.Photos.savedState and delete it.
That should give Photos a fresh start.